# exception in sqlite transaction c#

Tags: c#, database, transactions, command, executenonquery

I tried everything, but always , it returns me a System.NullreferencesException at "com.Transaction = trx;"

```
   public override int ExecuteNonQuery(string query)
    {

        int register=0;
        SQLiteTransaction trx=null;
        SQLiteCommand com;
        try
        {
            if (this.IsClosed()) this.Open();

                trx = con.BeginTransaction();
                com = new SQLiteCommand(query, con);
                com.Transaction = trx;
                register = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                trx.Commit();

            return register;
        }
        catch (SQLiteException ex)
        {
            trx.Rollback();//se tiene q deshaser toda la trransaccion hecha
            throw ex;
        }

        finally
        {
            this.Close();
        }

    }
```

i dont figure out where my error is :(

here is the exception that throws me in [transaction](http://imageshack.us/f/404/zu6c.png/)

**Update:**

Here are are The [Exception Detalis](http://img845.imageshack.us/img845/2080/5aqd.png)

Comment: Is this a cut down version? Because you don't need an explicit transaction for what you've posted.

Comment: It is weird that you get exception on this "com.Transaction = trx;" line. Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: i just upload the exception, yeah i dont know why transaction is null :(

Comment: could be the version?, but where i see that, in reference System.Data.Sqlite the version say 1.0.89.0

Comment: @RobertoMassimoPataraBrianco Can you just copy paste the full (text) stack trace here? The image you linked to is good but it is not the stack trace. I mean the one under the "View Details", it should be called something like "stack trace".

Comment: sry, It is too much to copy in whole text, i upload in a full image.

Comment: Hey Roberto :> this still does not show the stack trace. you need to click on the column in front of the "StackTrace" field and copy the containing text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fix it, the problem was with transaction, i think that sqlite doesn't support that, i commented it and all works like a charm.

```
  public override int ExecuteNonQuery(string query)
    {

        int register=0;
        //SQLiteTransaction trx=null;
        SQLiteCommand com;
        try
        {
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed) this.Open();

                //trx = con.BeginTransaction();//para hacer transaciones para que la base de datos este estable
                com = new SQLiteCommand(query, con);
                //com.Transaction = trx;
                register = com.ExecuteNonQuery();//recien hacemos la coneccion en esta linea
               // trx.Commit();

            return register;
        }
        catch (SQLiteException ex)
        {
           // trx.Rollback();//se tiene q deshaser toda la trransaccion hecha
            throw ex;
        }

        finally
        {
            this.Close();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace these lines

```
 if (this.IsClosed()) 
      this.Open();
```

with

```
 if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed) 
     con.Open();
```

Comment: I just did it, and keeps throw me System.NullreferencesException at "com.Transaction = trx;" :(

Comment: Really this problem seems weird. I was looking at the source code of the Transaction property of the SQLiteCommand and there is nothing that throws a NRE exception when you try to assign a value also if this value is null.

Comment: the value "trx" is with the conection open, and is not null